# Scroll Rect swipe functionality not working as expected on Android Build

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have a Scroll Rect component and a Content Fitter component attached to a UI panel in Unity 5.3.4 .The idea is that I will spawn a bunch of Buttons(as game Icons) for the user to browse through and select one based on their choice.I have selected the the Elastic Movement Type,with a sensitivity of 4 .The Scrolling works absolutely fine on the Unity Editor when I scroll around using my mouse however when I make an android build and try swiping it only works properly when I swipe from left to right but jitters and most of the time doesn't even respond when I swipe right to left.has someone else encountered this before ? Is there a potential fix for this?